# Bash run sh command stored in variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script like this one: (main script taking two args)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function runSh(){
  sh "$1"
}

if [ $(whoami) != "root" ]; then
   sesu root
fi

PATH="$1"

cd $PATH
for folders in */; do
   cd $folders
   for files in *; do
       if [[ $files == deploy_es* ]]; then
           runSh $files $2       ***it fail here with 'sh command not found', $files here is a sh script like `deploy_es_test.sh`***
       fi
   done
   cd ..
done
```

my question is, how can i run sh script stored in the variable `$files` ?

1. I tried to run it through runSh function,
2. with `eval $files $2`
3. with `$(sh $files $2)`

none works, i suppose i'm not using the good method to run it, thx for your help !

Comment: What happens if you just type `sh` on the command line interface?

Comment: seems ok, give me that `sh-4.2$`

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. Do not modify the `PATH` bash variable. It is special. It is the one bash uses to find other commands. As you modified it bash does not find anything anymore. It would issue the same error message about any other non-builtin utility.

Comment: `$PATH` is a special variable that controls how commands are found. I wouldn't change it.

Comment: thank you guys, help me so much ! ! :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't find `sh` is that you set PATH that is a special variable that defines the places where bash will look for binaries/scripts.

By setting `PATH="$1"` bash will not be able to find anything.

BTW: you don't really need to do that loop:

```
CMD="cat"
[ $(whoami) != "root" ] && CMD="sudo cat"
find $1 -maxdepth 1 -name deploy_es\* -exec $CMD {} \;
```

is probably enough.

As to the question you placed, bash doesn't require you to `eval` the command in general as you can see here:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/a
totale 4
-rw------- 1 root   sandro 5 dic 15 15:13 deploy_es.txt
$ CMD=cat
$ find /tmp/a -name deploy_es\* -exec $CMD {} \;
cat: /tmp/a/deploy_es.txt: Permesso negato
$ CMD="sudo cat"
$ find /tmp/a -name deploy_es\* -exec $CMD {} \;
ciao
```